# How to scale SVG symbol based on zoom level in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, symbology, svg

I am wondering if there is a way to scale SVG files I have stored as blob in a Spatialite database according to the current zoom level in QGIS. My hope is to have the SVG icon resize itself when the map is zoomed in/out. I understand there is a size option in the data defined option, but it does not seem to provide a dynamic sizing option. I am open to options.

Comment: Just realized that I'm actually not sure what the question is ... Can you provide a screenshot of your SVG label configuration? Are you talking about a SVG label background?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have an SVG Marker symbol layer, you can set the size units to map units. That way the icon will always have the same real-world size.

Note that the size in the data-defined properties is not radius or diameter but area - which I find weird and might be considered a bug.

Comment: Thank you @Underdark. This does what I want, however, I am working at a scale for North America, and there are sizing limits in QGIS. You can only use up to 5 digits, so the largest value I can use is 99999 map units, which is much too small for displaying a word cloud at a continent scale using the EPSG code of 3978. I suppose I may need to choose a different projection. Can you suggest another option?

Comment: Does the 5 digit limit also apply to the data-defined size? Should definitely be reported as a bug. The only bigger CRS units would be degrees as far as I can think of.

Comment: I am not sure about the data driven size. I thought degrees would be the only other option, unfortunately those projections are not visually pleasing.