# Scaling SVG symbols which are not label background on zoom level in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, svg

I need to scale the SVG symbols on zoom level.

@Underdarks answer in the posted question did not help me thus I can't set the SVG symbols as label background for I have labels which should not be overlaying the SVG.

[How to scale SVG symbol based on zoom level in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/128346/how-to-scale-svg-symbol-based-on-zoom-level-in-qgis)
[image]

Comment: It would also be great for a bit more explanation on why your question is different from the one you link to? Is @underdark's solution just not working for you or are you trying to achieve a slightly different thing than the original poster?

Comment: @JonoPatterson the original poster has the SVGs as label background. In the label settings it is possible to define the size units to map units.  But when adding the SVGs ass point symbols (instead of a blue or red circle) I only find the option to set a minimum and maximum scale (in general setting of layer properties). This would mean that I need to create multiple layers for different scale settings which does not seem to be a comfortable solution :/  yes, I am trying to achieve a slightly different thing than the original poster because my initial position is also slightly different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On QGIS 2.8 there is an option to scale SVG symbology with map units for me? it's on the style tab of layer properties:

Here:
[image: Map Unit Option]

Or:

[image: SVG Marker Units]

However you could also achieve what you want with a data defined approach:
(use $scale with CASE ELSE maybe)

[image: Data defined]

Or rule based styles. Here you establish all the sizes you need at the appropriate zoom levels for example between 1:100,000 and 1:200,000 zoom it needs a 4mm svg icon.

Then for each zoom level create a rule with an appropriate sized marker?

You'd end up with something like:

[image: Rule based styles]

Try all these out to find what works best for your challenge :)

Comment: Great that's it! I was looking in "General"...sometimes it's too easy to see!